# Running Mallet in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, mallet

So I'm using Mallet to create a simple tagger app.
 I know how to use it in command prompt and already made classifier model.
 So now how can i call that model in a code so i can make an interface out of it. 
Because the I can only load the model using just the command prompt. 
I tried to look in the Mallet page but its not in there. Anyone know how? 
I really need this guys so please  help me. 
TIA.

TRAING AND CREATING THE MODEL

> java -cp "C:\Mallet\class;C:\Mallet\lib\mallet-deps.jar"
>   cc.mallet.fst.SimpleTagger --train true --model-file
>   stopwords_tagger.txt output_1.txt

EXECUTING THE MODEL

> java -cp "C:\Mallet\class;C:\Mallet\lib\mallet-deps.jar"
>   cc.mallet.fst.SimpleTagger --include-input true --model-file
>   stopwords_tagger.txt data_2.txt

Answer (score 0):

You should download jar file of mallet in this [link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/cc.mallet/mallet/2.0.7) and added it in netbeans (path: properties-> libraries-> add jar/foldeer) . also you probably should add mallet-deps.jar and trove-2.0.2.jar. 
so you can write your java program in netbeans.

Comment: Is there any way in MALLET to do like this: STANFORD NER where you can call the model to create a Tagger Object. For example: 
`stanford_classifier = 'C:\\Users\\Acer\\Documents\\Thesis\\Tools\\stanford_ner\\classifiers\\english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz'
stanford_ner_path = 'C:\\Users\\Acer\\Documents\\Thesis\\Tools\\stanford_ner\\stanford-ner.jar'

# Creating Tagger Object
st = StanfordNERTagger(stanford_classifier, stanford_ner_path, encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: I don't know. You can run Stanford classifier and then passed the result to mallet algorithms.